# How to start counting a specific List elements based on a given index, and a condition?

Tags: c#, linq, list, count

```
var traps = new List<trap>();
if(traps.Count(x => x.trapToughness == tough.weak) => 5)
{
    //Some Code
}
```

I don't want the count method to start counting from the beginning of the List.

I have a local variable which holds the index(0,5,10,...)

Comment: `Skip(startCountingIndex).Count(...)`

Comment: Or `SkipWhile()`? Your question can be interpreted in multiple ways. It would help to see what you tried, or at least sample input/output.

Comment: Make a classic loop starting from the index you want and checking the condition you want. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var traps = new List<trap>();
var counter = traps.Skip(indexVariableToStartFrom)
                   .Count(x => x.trapToughness == tough.weak);

If(counter >= 5) 
{
    // Some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` clause includes an index as the second parameter. This is the index of the item in the `IEnumerable`

```
var traps = new List<trap>();
if(traps.Where((x, y) => x.trapToughness == tough.weak && y > INDEX)
                          .Count() >= 5)
{
    //Some Code
}
```